# How do I display a title excerpt in next post link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having problems displaying a title excerpt on a next post link.

If the characters are more than 30 for the next posts title i would just like it to show '...'

This is the code I use for title excerpts

```
 <?php short_title('...', 25); ?>
```

And this is the code I use for next post links

```
 <?php next_post_link( '<span class="pn-a">%link</span>', '<span class="pn-a">%title</span>' ) ?>
```

Short Title Function

```
function short_title($after = '', $length) {
$mytitle = get_the_title();
if ( strlen($mytitle) > $length ) {
$mytitle = substr($mytitle,0,$length);
echo $mytitle . $after;
} else {
echo $mytitle;
}
```

}

Any help?

Comment: Does the function short_title echo the trimed title?

Comment: Yes it does. That there is doing it to 25 characters.

Comment: Can you add the function to your answer?

Comment: Why not feed the title into your function instead of generating it inside the function? Then also return the result instead of echoing it in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are :)

Change your function like this, remove the echo and just return the value for the title

```
function short_title_next_post($after = '', $length) {
    $next = get_adjacent_post(1, '', 0);
    $mytitle = $next->post_title;
    if ( strlen($mytitle) > $length ) {
        $mytitle = substr($mytitle,0,$length);
        return $mytitle . $after;
    } else {
        return $mytitle;
    }
}
```

And then in the next_post_link simply call that function

```
next_post_link( '<span class="pn-a">%link</span>', '<span class="pn-a">' . short_title_next_post('...', 25) . '</span>'  );
```

:)

Comment: Thanks but now it isnt linking to the next post? Any help on allowing it to link a href wise? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to change the function... Working now :)!

Comment: Glad that I could help :) You can now accept the answer so the question can be closed :)

Comment: Hello Bojan, Ive just noticed it doesnt work properly. Basically that code feeds in the title of the current post, not the title of the next post. Any help? Thanks

Comment: I have updated the function. Now it will take the next post title and I changed the name to short_title_next_post(). :)